# DataContractSerializer -- How can I determine list of types/collections

Tags: vb.net, serialization, reflection

I have a complex object and I am trying to serialize using DataContractSerializer()

Works fine but I have to explicitly pass in the list of known possible types (collections, etc).

I want to dynamically (using reflection) traverse the entire graph and look for types and store them in a list and pass that list to DataContractSerializer.

I have googled but clearly used the wrong keywords, how would I accomplish this?

Sorry for the basic question I am total newbie to vb (only a week or so in).

Comment: why do YOU need to look for this stuff? If you decorate properties for the serializer, it will find them for you.  That said, it is possible to stash all sorts of stuff in a List or Dictionary to be fed to a serializer.  If you know what you are after, just get it and place it in the collection (and if you dont know, how will you find it thru Reflection?) Also, I would be remiss if I did not mention that ProtoBuf-NET is a smaller, faster replacement alternative for binary serialization.

Comment: We ended up solving the issues (rather our more experienced .net guy did). We wanted a generic solution, if I had to explicitly state the objects that would make it less dynamic.